# jQuery and CSS media query dont match

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have insert a CSS code to an element to show it only on mobile:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) { #footer {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 1rem;
z-index: 10;
}}
```

So far works great. then i added this jQuery, to display it in on scroll.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

if (jQuery(this).scrollTop()>100)
{
jQuery('#footer').fadeIn();
}
else
{
jQuery('#footer').fadeOut();
}
});
```

but now, the element is shown on PC as well. what do i need to insert into the JS code in order to tell him no to show it on PC?
thanks.

Comment: All jQuery knows is it's running in a browser.

Comment: Media queries do also have the concept of a min-width

Comment: `fadeIn` changes the `opacity`. You can still change other properties. Try using `display:none` for PC devices using media queries. So as said above: `min-width: 780px`

Comment: I already tried by inserting media query min width and display none with no success. There is nothing to change in the JS code?

Comment: @media only screen and (min-width: 780px) { #footer {
display:none;
}}

min-width works well without the jquery code. when i add the jquery, it shows on PC screen. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `display: none` to your footer by default. Then, wrap the code that checks the scroll position in an `if` statement that checks the window's width.

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  if (jQuery(window).width() <= 780) {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100)
    {
      jQuery('#footer').fadeIn();
    }
    else
    {
      jQuery('#footer').fadeOut();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  height: 300vh;
}

#footer {
  display: none;
  background: #dfd;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  #footer {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    z-index: 10;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<footer id="footer">This is my footer.</footer>
```